# Django - Celery Connection Refused

Tags: python, django, celery

My site is having 502 errors when the user requests something that requires the server to send an e-mail. I narrowed it down to an issue with celery, but I'm having problems resolving it. I tried to get celery's status, and I received a connection refused error (traceback below). I restarted all the processes using supervisor as well. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.0.24', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    main()

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 957, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 901, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 187, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(prog_name, argv[1:])

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 893, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 868, in execute
    return cls(app=self.app).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 148, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 118, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 661, in run
    'ping', **dict(kwargs, quiet=True, show_body=False))

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 511, in run
    return self.do_call_method(args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 535, in do_call_method
    replies = handler(method, *args[1:], **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 578, in call
    return getattr(i, method)(*args)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 81, in ping
    return self._request('ping')

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 55, in _request
    timeout=self.timeout, reply=True,

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 269, in broadcast
    limit, callback, channel=channel,

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 259, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 776, in default_channel
    self.connection

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 761, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 720, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 115, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 264, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)

File "/home/ubuntu/Installs/my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 99, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: When you list processes from `ps ax` are your amqp and celery services running? My hunch is some service(s) is(are) not being started automatically and the communication socket is not being created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your broker back-end ? (The value of BROKER_URL in celery config file )

Is rabbitmq-server running? if not run it:

```
service rabbitmq start
```

And then restart your celery script.